# How to create this layout in Drawable Resource and make it as background in activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image: Picture Reference]

I just want to create and display the example picture on top as a background in activity. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to design this layout

**first** set image as a background like this

```
android:background="@drawable/dummy"
```

**Second** create custom layout and used as a back ground like this

> laout_custom_bg.xml (add in layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:background="#fff"/>
    <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:background="#2196F3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_custom_bg"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FF9800"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Write on your xml : android:background=@drawable/imgname.extension

This must be on your

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout, it's children can have elevations (heights on the z-axis).
So you put the background picture to match parent (in width and height),and it's elevation 0.Then all other views have elevation >0.

Edit:you can also use Constraint Layout as in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@yourpicturesource" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    ...other views



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to create the view.

I have used `LinearLayout` here for the same.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   >

   <View
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight=1
     android:background="#FFFFFF"
   />

   <View
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight=3
     android:background="#0000FF"
   />
</LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

**getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.example);**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.example);
}
```